# omniORB::MaxMessageSize in omni 4

Tags: c++, corba, omnicomplete

I am working on a porting project where omni3 has been used.  Now we are integrating it with omni 4 which omniORB::MaxMessageSize function is not supported. Anyone know from which function we have to substitute it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. Substitute is

CORBA::ULong giopMaxMsgSize